# Google Place API returning null sometimes

Tags: python, google-maps, google-places-api

Using a python script to grab Google Place addresses.

Occasionally `city` returns `null`, however Google clearly has the city info.

Most of the time it grabs the city correctly (and City is the only data that does this)

```
#address 
city=""
if "address_components" in restrauntObj["result"].keys():
    addComponents=restrauntObj["result"]["address_components"]
    for i in range(len(addComponents)):
        if addComponents[i]["types"][0]=="locality":
            city=addComponents[i]["long_name"]

customRestObject["City"]=city
```

Comment: Do you have an example query or data?

Comment: @geocodezip Turns out in NYC, there's something called [sublocality](http://i.imgur.com/GKg8bvP.png). My code only looks for `locality`. How can I search for `sublocality` if `locality` is unavailable/null?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out certain places have sublocalities (ie: nyc). So you need to add the sublocality if its available.

```
if addComponents[i]["types"][0]=="sublocality_level_1":
    subcity=addComponents[i]["long_name"]
```